# Android widget text looks blurry

Tags: android, widget

Drawing widget text looks very blurry compared to launcher icon text of roughly the same size. Found some tricks here at Stackoverflow but they didn't help.

How can I use the same sharp font as the launcher?

[image: Screenshot]

Code used to draw:

```
Bitmap drawWidget(JSONArray result) {
    int pixelsize = (int)Math.round(72.0 * SettingsActivity.density);
    if (pixelsize > 0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "pixel size = " + pixelsize);
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(pixelsize, pixelsize, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        Paint p = new Paint(Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        p.setAntiAlias(true);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        p.setTextSize(10f);

        int y = 10;

        for (TemperatureItem t : temperatureItems) {
            double temp = getTemperature(result, t.getName());
            c.drawText(t.getName() + ": " + temp, 0, y, p);
            y += 10;
        }
        c.drawText(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()), 0, y, p);
        return b;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
```

Widget provider:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widgetlayout"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:minWidth="72dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000" >

</appwidget-provider>
```

Widget layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0dip"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/update"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="0dip"
        android:text="Static Text" >
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try another flag [Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that with every combination of the other two flags.  There is no visible change.

Comment: maybe look for widget sizing, as I know some devices (UI overlays like TouchWiz for Samsungs) have hardcoded margins, so widgets cannot touch their edges. It might be really old and obsolete case (maybe for 2.x Android and old versions of overlays). So if real size is e.g. 64 dp (4dp margin for each side) then your bitmap is rescaled (have you tried `CENTER_CROP` for `scaleType` ImageView's param?)

Comment: Yes, that must be it. The formula 70 x n - 30 for my 1x1 widget equals 40. Screen density is 1.0, so my widget is assumed to be 40 pixels wide. Used a ruler to guess its actual size and it's closer to 120 pixels.

Comment: use `imageView.getMeasuredHeight();` after view is drawn. you might also let the iamgeView to be drew empty (with 'fill_parent' or 'match_parent'), then measure it and add this dimen as param for you method `Bitmap drawWidget(JSONArray result, int pixelSize)` without line geting "hardcoeded" 72 dp

Comment: Hmm, not sure there is a way to access the view hierarchy of a widget.

Comment: Using a large bitmap (256x256) solved the problem for now. Since I'm developing this for private use, I won't go into the mess of figuring out widget sizes for portrait/landscape mode. Thanks again for your help.